# Prevent default creation of MongoDB database programmatically

Tags: mongodb, casbah

Is there a way to check for the existence of Mongo Database via Java API without creating the database on initiating the call?

I am currently using Casbah (Scala Driver) to interact with our Mongo Instance

```
val mongo = MongoConnection(List(new ServerAddress("localhost",27017)))
val db = mongo.getDB("testXXX")
```

The API `getDB` seems to create a database by default and I would not want this to occur

If `testXXX` does not exist, I would *NOT* want Mongo to create a database but instead let me as the consumer decide whether it exists

Is there such an API via MongoDB java driver or Casbah?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the following (also with Casbah / Scala):

```
val dbExists = !mongo.dbNames.contains("testXXX")
```

Comment: Might be an expensive operation if the instance contains over 100,000+ dbs .. I implemented a alternate solution where, I introspect if collection(s) exists and if not, I drop the created database .. Not the best solution but it does not involve linear search across all databases

Comment: Good point - in our context, we know we've only got at most tens of dbs.

Answer (score 2):

By default the database won't be created on the server until you ask that database for a collection.

So you can do `val db = mongo.getDB("testXXX")` and a database called "testXXX" won't be created on your MongoDB server until you call something like `db.getCollection("myCollectionName")`.